# What does the following code does?

Tags: function

I was given in university the following code to explain shortly what it does and what is the value of x at the end of the run as a function of n, hope someone could help me.

```
x = 0;
for(int i = n; i > 1; i--) {
    for(int j = 1; j < i; j--) {
        x +=5;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: for(int j = 1; j < i; i--)

There is a bug right there in the second for loop. So only god knows what the code will do.

Comment: You were given the assignment because the instructor wants to see your work (not ours). You should do it yourself. If you can't figure it out, ask your instructor for help; either they have not yet done their job of providing you the necessary knowledge or you've been inattentive in class. Good luck.

Comment: @user2260040 ohh it was my mistake, edited

Comment: surely it is faster to run it on an online compiler rather than asking a question here?

Comment: It does an eternal loop on the 2nd one. So you could say to your tutor that "The second loop is a bullshit". @user2260040 You have a typo there..

Comment: Its OK to ask that here as long as `asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.` https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . And, the for loop conditions do seem odd, but ideally @ScarlettLux should say more about it first.

Comment: @choz - OP fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you meant to write "j++" instead of "j--", and not end up in an infinite loop?)

If so, just execute it by hand.

The outer loop iterates with i over the integers, from n down to 2 (inclusive).

At each iteration of that loop, the inner loop iterates with j over the integers from 1 up to i - 1 (inclusive).

thus, x is incremented by 5 for each of:

j = 1, 2, ... n - 1

then, each of:

j = 1, 2, ... n - 2

then, etc,

...

until,

j = 1

if I'm not mistaken, that's n * (n - 1) / 2 iterations in total

(cf. the arithmetic progression)

to give eventually,

x == 5 * n * (n - 1) / 2

E.g., for n = 3:

x == 15

'HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = n; i > 1; i--) {
for(int j = 1; j < i; j--) {
```

since i > 1 and j=1; j < i; j--.
j will always be less than i so it becomes an infinite loop.